# How to align image to the right using Bootstrap Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am new to Bootstrap vue and attempting to align an image to the right using b-card header.  I'm trying to use  with span or .  The template header is perfect in size until I add the image and the image also shows a bit underneath but it is on the right.  Here is my codepen.  Any assistance you may provide would be wonderful.

https://codepen.io/tone373/pen/JjeYazG

```
<b-card header-tag="header">
  
  <template #header>
    <h4>b-img</h4>
    <b-img right src="https://picsum.photos/125/125/?image=58" alt="Right image"></b-img>
  </template>

   </b-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap `grid` system:

```
<b-card header-tag="header">
  <template #header>
    <b-row align-h="between" class="align-items-center">
      <h4 class="mb-0">b-img</h4>
      <b-col cols="auto">
        <b-img right src="https://picsum.photos/125/125/?image=58" alt="Right image"></b-img>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </template>
</b-card>
```

`b-row` with `align-h="between"` aligns the elements horizontally with space between them. The `<h4>` and the image is placed inside the 1st and 2nd column and `cols="auto"` in `b-col` adjusts the width automatically.

Comment: Thank alot.  Just for kicks if I wanted to align the image vertically under the text why doesn't aligh-v work?

Comment: If you want to put one under the other and center them, change inside of `<template>` tag:

 ```<b-row align-h="center">
                <h4 class="mb-0">b-img</h4>
            </b-row>
            <b-row align-h="center">
               <b-img  src="https://picsum.photos/125/125/?image=58" alt="Right image"></b-img>
            </b-row>```